# Why does window.location not work in my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

stackoverflower:
I met a quite strange problem, here is my sample code:

```
export default class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(){
        //do some expression
        window.location = 'url I want to jump'
    }

    render(){
      return <button onClick={this.handleClick}/> 
   }
}
```

but when invoked `handleClick`, my spa will not jump to the url which, instead, it did nothing. The problem be solved when replace with following code :

```
 handleClick(){
   setTimeout(()=>{window.location = 'url I want to jump'}) 
}
```

It seems I met js single thread problem, and `setTimeout` or `nextTick` can solve the problem

can you explain this?

by the way, the running environment is under a customized MVC with react-like， redux-like package. maybe is the MVC inner black magic rather than single thread caused my trouble

thx

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with   `window.location`?

Comment: In reality, it is a logout module. it will open logout page which is an validated url

Answer (score 2):

This is not much of an answer per-se but just to illustrate.
Your code should work perfectly fine no matter what server environment you have, as `window.location` runs on the client side.

```js
 class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    //do some expression
    window.location = 'https://google.com'
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>click</button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyAwesomeComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code may indicate that something wrong with my MVC but nothing about react